# Determinant of a propagator in Effective potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-electrodynamics, propagator, 1pi-effective-action

Last days I have a hard time calculating the Effective potential in Scalar Quantum Electrodynamics. Right now I stuck in the following determinant

$$ Det\left[(-k^2+e^2\phi_c^2)g_{\mu\nu}+k_\mu k_\nu \right] $$

where $e$ is the particles charge, $k_\mu$ is his momentum, and $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the Minkowski space metric.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: One thing you can try if you don't have any other ideas: just write down the $4\times 4$ matrix and compute it brute-force.

Comment: I know but is there another option?

Answer (score 3):

This question can be answered using the *matrix determinant lemma* which states that,
$$\det \left(A +uv^{T}\right) = \left(1+v^T A^{-1}u \right)\det A$$

where $A$ is a matrix and $uv^T$ is the outer product. In this case, we have,

$$\det[(-k^2+e^2\phi^2)g_{\mu\nu} + k_\mu k_\nu] = \left(1 + \frac{1}{-k^2+e^2\phi^2}k_\nu g^{\mu\nu}k_\mu \right) \det[(-k^2+e^2\phi^2)g_{\mu\nu}].$$

Simplifying, and noting that $\det(\alpha A) = \alpha^D \det A$ in $D$ dimensions, one has for the determinant,

$$= \left(1 + \frac{k^2}{-k^2+e^2\phi^2} \right) \left(-k^2+e^2\phi^2 \right)^D g$$

where $g := \det(g_{\mu\nu})$. If $g_{\mu\nu}= \mathrm{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$ this reduces to,

$$\boxed{\det[(-k^2+e^2\phi^2)\eta_{\mu\nu} + k_\mu k_\nu]=-e^2\phi^2 (e^2\phi^2-k^2)^3.}$$

Comment: Nice! I'll try to remember this :-)

Comment: The solution is wrong because you didn't make careful contraction in the indexes when you put out $g^{\mu\nu}$

Comment: @JonSnow I don't have time to correct it right now but if you can't apply the lemma yourself using what I've provided then you have larger issues than studying field theory.

Comment: Thenks for the advice. I'll check